# Microservices - API Gateway Layer

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, cloud-foundry

I have read few details of use of api gateway in microservices architecture. I have read that it basically helps with security , transformation , throttling etc. Is orchestration also one of it responsibilities? When I read about microservices , I saw that it should have dumb pipes and smart endpoints and services must be choreographed and not orchestrated. So my assumption is that orchestration is not a responsibility  of api gateway.

Comment: Can you please let me know why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably no orchestation but there is a pattern called API Gateway

> Using an API Gateway
>
> Usually a much better approach is to use what is known as an API
>   Gateway. An API Gateway is a server that is the single entry point
>   into the system. It is similar to the Facade pattern from
>   object-oriented design. The API Gateway encapsulates the internal
>   system architecture and provides an API that is tailored to each
>   client. It might have other responsibilities such as authentication,
>   monitoring, load balancing, caching, request shaping and management,
>   and static response handling. pattern call API Gateway

https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/

http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html?utm_source=building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway&utm_medium=blog

https://www.nginx.com/blog/microservices-reference-architecture-nginx-proxy-model/

Comment: Thanks reos , my assumptions is the it provides all the capabilities listed by you but doesn't provide a coarse grained service layer by calling 2 or more micro services. Is that right ?

Comment: The API Gateway is responsible for request routing, composition, and protocol translation. All requests from clients first go through the API Gateway. It then routes requests to the appropriate microservice. The API Gateway will often handle a request by invoking multiple microservices and aggregating the results. It can translate between web protocols such as HTTP and WebSocket and web-unfriendly protocols that are used internally.

Comment: A major benefit of using an API Gateway is that it encapsulates the internal structure of the application. Rather than having to invoke specific services, clients simply talk to the gateway. The API Gateway provides each kind of client with a specific API. This reduces the number of round trips between the client and application. It also simplifies the client code.

Comment: Thanks reos , it provides a coarse grained service layer as you mentioned then! But I don't believe it still qualifies as orchestration. Please correct me if I am wrong . Thank you

Comment: Yes, it not orchestation as a business workflow but it let you aggregate different microservices responses.

Comment: @reos - Isn't aggregation going to be considered as a business logic? Is that going to violate Smart Endpoint Dumb Pipe paradigm?

Comment: @Divs I think it is not business logic because the services can exists without aggregation and they will do everything in the way you want. E.g Amazon can show a product page with product description (service1) and reviews (Service 2) the two services can work well without aggregation but you can use aggregation in order to do the same thing in only one invocation.

Comment: @reos - Yes, Service 1 and Service 2 may or may not need business logic during aggregation. But if it does, can we call Dumb Endpoint any more? Or to comply, we always handle any business logic for aggregation in a composite service and let Gateway invoke it?

Comment: @Divs The aggregation process is not business logic. In the example that I gave you each service do its own business logic. The aggregation process only join both responses in one. If you need business logic it needs to be in the service logic. Aggregation is not Business logic.